# Precedence of RewriteRules in .htaccess file on Apache Server

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, rewrite

I have a number of RewriteRules in my .htaccess file. However, one specific rule is only executed if I remove another specific rule, regardless of how I order the two rules.

Here's the rule which seems to have "lower" priority:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /beta/forward.php?id=$1 [L]
```

And here's the rule which always takes precedence:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Both domain1 and domain2 actually point to the same web site. So, whenever both rules are in the .htaccess file and I access

```
http://domain1.net/123
```

The second rule gets executed first and I get two redirects, first to http://domain2.net/123 and then (when the host name doesn't fit the second rule anymore) to http://domain2.net/beta/forward.php?id=123. I've tried fixing the second rule so it is never executed for urls which only contain numbers, but I must be doing something wrong, because it *still* gets executed:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ domain1\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*[^0-9]+.*)$ http://domain2.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Only be removing the two lines from the .htaccess file can I get the first rule to handle the request right away.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rules indicate these procedures:

> If the URL is only numbers, go to the beta URL followed by those numbers and stop.
>
> If you visit domain1, go to the same URL at domain2 and stop.

When an `L` is encountered or the rules are finished, the processing ends.  Anything else happening is a new connection from the browser. This is probably what is confusing for you—the order matters, then the matches.  The `L` should take care of the problem you have when they're in order:

> `RewriteEngine on`
>
> `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /beta/forward.php?id=$1 [L]` # end of processing [L] if it's only numeric
>
> `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.net$ [NC]` # if case-insensitive match of domain1.net…
>
> `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.net/$1 [R=301,L]` # redirect to domain2.net. End [L]

Comment: Right, I got confused by the fact that the browser started a second connection which I didn't see in its UI anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check the flags of the rewrite rules (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) pay attention to what C and L flags do.

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for a documentation of all the flags.